# Getting ModuleNotFoundError while running Beam pipeline on Google Dataproc, how to fix?

Tags: apache-beam, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run a Beam pipeline written in PythonSDK on Google Dataproc. As mentioned in the doc here https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/ I am bundling everything into a jar and submitting it to a Dataproc cluster. However I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) (sparkrunnertest-w-1.us-west1-b.c.research-prototypes.internal executor 2): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 285, in loads
    return dill.loads(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 462, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxx'
```

To give more details, I am using a ParDo transform in my pipeline which invokes a functions defined in another file which depends upon various other internal and external python modules.

The example in the SparkRunner doc seems to be pretty simple, running on a single file. How to run it when I have a complex directory structure. Are there some extra PipelineOptions that I need to set. I am trying to migrate a job from Dataflow to Dataproc to see if it reduces running costs.